# Dockerfile commands not executing in MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, azure-devops

I am trying to build a container using docker file which has some statements to execute as below:

```
# Create folder for caching files
RUN mkdir -p /Library/WebServer/docroot/publish
RUN chown -R daemon:daemon /Library/WebServer/docroot
```

I am using below command to build :

```
$ docker build --no-cache -t dispatcher-apache -f Dockerfile
```

I can see the below execution :

```
Step 7/10 : RUN mkdir -p /Library/WebServer/docroot/publish
 ---> Running in 4c8f7c3e2238
```

But the file isn't created on that location when I check.

```
-bash: cd: /Library/WebServer/docroot/publish: No such file or directory
```

However, if I create commands from terminal, it works fine.

```
Dockerfile :
FROM httpd:2.4

# Copy dispatcher module
RUN mkdir -p /private/libexec/apache2/
COPY ./apache2-modules/ /private/libexec/apache2/
RUN ln -s /private/libexec/apache2/dispatcher-apache2.4-4.2.3.so /private/libexec/apache2/mod_dispatcher.so


# Copy new apache dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /private/etc/apache2/conf
COPY ./publish/etc/httpd/conf.d/ /private/etc/apache2/conf/


# Create folder for caching files
RUN mkdir -p /Library/WebServer/docroot/publish
RUN chown -R daemon:daemon /Library/WebServer/docroot


# Create folder for log files
RUN mkdir -p /private/var/log/apache2


# Replace httpd.conf with enabled modules
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

**EDIT after some help:**

Now after build, I started the container and below is the error

```
$ docker run -dit -e HOSTIP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0) --rm --name dispatcher-app -p 8080:80 dispatcher-apache
6a032a50be846bef06027976b990da27bcb446c28d582cf6c3a4dc4ad4361e1c

$ docker exec -it dispatcher-app /bin/bash
Error: No such container: dispatcher-app
```

Any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: do you mean this directory `/Library/WebServer/docroot/publish` doesn't exists inside container

Comment: This directory meant to be create what I think. But this is not getting create.

Comment: Can you provide complete `dockerfile` and the `docker run` command

Comment: updated docker file contents.

Comment: I tried it at my end I can see that directory exists inside my container.

Comment: Where and how do you execute your bash command, which throws the error?

Comment: @zdhim I doubt you are looking for this directory `/Library/WebServer/docroot/publish` on your Mac OS on which you ran docker build command. In that case it will definitely will not be available on your host. That dir will exists inside your container, because whatever you run inside dockerfile will get executed inside docker container and wrapped into docker image.

Comment: docker exec failed because I doubt your container has failed/crashed. Check `docker ps` make sure its running

Comment: @mchawre : No Container listed on ps command

Comment: that means your docker container failed/crashed. Run `docker ps -a` get the container-id. Now check the logs of failed container using `docker logs container-id`